# Notify users when questions that they answered are placed on hold

Tags: feature-request

Users who answer a question should be notified of the question being placed on hold, because there is a good chance that they could provide critical insight into why the question should be re-opened.

This applies to most closing types:

- **Unclear** - since the question was clear enough for you to write an answer, you are in a good position to propose an edit that clarifies the question to others,
- **Too broad** - since you provided an answer covering a specific area, you can propose an edit to give the question a narrower focus,
- **Duplicate** - you have more insight into the question than users who didn't answer the question, so you could propose an edit that stresses the uniqueness of that question.

Comment: Related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/please-notify-us-when-a-question-we-ask-or-answer-is-closed-or-reopened

Comment: @PaulRoub This is different from the question at the link, which asks to notify the author of the question, not people who answered the question.

Comment: It's titled "Please notify us when a question we ask **or answer** is closed or reopened" (emphasis mine), so it's hard to argue it's not *somewhat* related.

Comment: @PaulRoub I see - the question is closed as a duplicate, so I immediately followed the link. I guess the question that you linked should be reopened.